# C++ error: 'count_of_function_calls' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, function, declaration

hi I am new to c++ and I am stuck in a question. I am a beginner, please help me, that you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int dostuff ()
{
    return 2 + 3;
}
void fun ()
{
    count_of_function_calls++;
}

int main()
{

    void fun ();
void fun ();
void fun();
cout << "Function fun was called" << count_of_function_calls << "times"; 
}
```

Comment: Btw, `void fun();` - not a function call. And `count_of_function_calls` indeed was not declared in that scope (any scope).

Comment: You should stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error, it will get you nowhere. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen _"You should stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error ..."_ And if so, OP shouldn't ask about the errors here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not an interactive tutorial.

Comment: The link is not yet appeared somehow, so here it is: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

Many, many problems, you should definitely read a C++ book or reread some tutorials

---

Where did you define `count_of_function_calls`?

Nowhere, that's why the compiler is complaining. You *always* have to declare variables before you use them:

```
int count_of_function_calls = 0;
```

Note that in your case, because you want to value of `count_of_function_calls` to be incremented for each function call, you should declare it as a global variable (this is *not recommended*, consider using something else).

A global variable is declared outside of any scope, in your case, you could for example defined it just above `void fun ()`.

---

`void fun ();` declares a function (called `fun`), taking no arguments and returning `void`. It **doesn't** call the function `fun`. If you want to call a function, you don't have to specify the return type:

```
//Call function 'fun'
fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to define global variable `count_of_function_calls`

For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int count_of_function_calls;

int dostuff ()
{
    return 2 + 3;
}
void fun ()
{
    count_of_function_calls++;
}

//...
```

And the function calls must look like

```
fun();
```

This

```
void fun ();
```

is a function declaration. It is not a call of the function.